# How to make an Azure EnterPrise Application as Owner of a Client's Tenant Programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, fluent

B2B concept for Cloud Service Provider,

1. A Business - Global Administrator logs into my application
2. Grants access to enterprise application for accessing his tenant and create a Azure AD - APP
3. Once the AD - APP is created , creating a Service principal is my next step.
4. After creating service principal, need to assign a role to created app [New 
   Application on my client's tenant].

An error is thrown up as below :

The client 'xxxxx' with object id 
'xxxxx  does not have authorization to 
perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/read' over scope 
'/subscriptions/yyyyy'.

xxxx-  [ApplicationID which is Authenticated on Global Admin login]
yyyy - [SubscriptionID on which am trying to create a service principal and add a role].

Am a C# developer using Azure.Fluent API for doing the above.

Developing an azure function for automation the whole process.

Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated.

I have verified using below cases as

Granting the My APP as owner on Client's Tenant

To keep it simple - How to make an Azure EnterPrise Application as Owner of a Client's Tenant

The client 'xxxxx' with object id 
'xxxxx  does not have authorization to 
perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/read' over scope 
'/subscriptions/yyyyy'.

or How to Grant a role to azure ad enterprise application using fluent api

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your app needs to act as the user in their Azure subscription.
You'd most likely only use this for creating the role assignment for your app.

[image: Add required permissions / Azure Service Management API]

If you add the above permission as a required permission for your app,
you should be able to make the necessary call to create the role assignment.
(as long as the user has the rights to make them)

Note that you'll need to call the API on behalf of the user.
This means you'll have to use a delegated authentication flow like Authorization Code flow and get an access token that way.

Comment: @Junas, Thanks for the response, used Authorization code flow and made it happen using a graph API.